# When does the C++ standard permits/forces the compiler to devirtualization?

Tags: c++

Given the following example, consider we run it in C++17 at O2 opt level. The result shows that the clang compiler will directly call `Derived::foo` rather than refer to vtable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Base {
public:
    virtual __attribute__ ((noinline)) void foo() { std::cout << "Base::foo()" << std::endl; }
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void __attribute__ ((noinline)) foo() override { std::cout << "Derived::foo()" << std::endl; }
};

class DerivedDerived : public Derived {
public:
    virtual void __attribute__ ((noinline)) foo() override { std::cout << "DerivedDerived::foo()" << std::endl; }
};

class DerivedDerived2: public Derived {
public:
    virtual void __attribute__ ((noinline)) foo() override { std::cout << "DerivedDerived2::foo()" << std::endl; }
};

class DerivedDerived3: public DerivedDerived {
public:
    virtual void __attribute__ ((noinline)) foo() override { std::cout << "DerivedDerived3::foo()" << std::endl; }
};


Derived *create(int derived) {
    // srand(time(NULL));
    if (!derived)
        return new Derived();
    else if(derived == 1)
        return new DerivedDerived();
    else if(derived == 2)
        return new DerivedDerived2();
    return new DerivedDerived3();
}

void test() {
    Derived *b = create(0);
    b->foo();
    delete b;
}
```

However, if I add `__attribute__ ((noinline))` to `create` and `test`, the compiler will no longer to do such optimization.

Meanwhile, if the `create` uses a random value to decide if what class will be created, then the compiler has no choice but to refer to vtable.

I wonder if there is a section in the standard that specifies whether a compiler can do a devirtualization?

***UPDATED***

I want to know this because if I want to call without referring vtable, I used to use `o.foo()` rather than `o->foo()`. However, there are some cases where a pointer is preferred for some other reason. For example, I wonder is it guaranteed "vtable"-free in the following code. If it is no, then if it is a good practice to do so, since some compilers I tested actually does devirtualization.

```
// T is derived from a Base class, and may have derived classes itself.
TPtr create() {
    return new T();
}

void test() {
    TPtr p = create();
    p->foo();
}
```

Comment: The standard doesn't describe optimizations that don't have any observable effect other than execution speed, it just allows all of them (the as-if rule).

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I updated my question, so can I do what in my updated question?

Comment: The answer to the update is the same, the standard doesn't specify this. What you do is take your compiler (or the three big compilers), and inspect the resulting assembly on https://gcc.godbolt.org/. If you don't like what you see, you start thinking.

Comment: Brainstorm question : If you want to be able to call functions without vtable why don't you switch to static polymorphism instead? And use the CRTP/mixin approach to reuse code?

Answer (score 1):

You need not and you should not consider implementation details for deciding how to write code (except for rare cases, but this isn't one of them). The standard doesn't mention the virtual table at all, in particular it does not set rules for when it has to be used and when not. It rather specifies how virtual dispatch is supposed to behave. `b->foo();` calls the right method, so all is fine.

> ... because if I want to call without referring vtable ...

In your code you typically never "refer to the vtable", you write code to call a method. And your distinction between `o.foo()`  and `o->foo()` is moot. What matters is not `.` or `->`, but whether you use pointers or references.

This will call `T::foo`:

```
 T t;
 t.foo();
```

This two examples will make use of virtual dispatch when `foo` is virtual in `Base` and `Derived` inherits publicly from `Base`:

```
 Base* b = get_pointer_from_somewhere();
 b->foo();
 Base& c = *b; // or get_reference_from_somewhere()
 c.foo();
```

> I wonder if there is a section in the standard that specifies whether a compiler can do a devirtualization?

No there isn't. The standard specifies how virtual dispatch is supposed to behave. How this is realized is up to the implementation.
There is a section in the standard that is commonly referred to as the "as-if rule". It grants compilers the freedom to apply transformations and optimizations to code as long as the observable behavior is as specified in the standard. For details I refer you to [What exactly is the "as-if" rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule).

Comment: I mean in some cases `Base* b = get_pointer_from_somewhere(); b->fool()` could also result in direct call

Comment: @calvin it doesnt matter whether you have `Base& b = get_reference();` or `Base* b = get_pointer();`. In my answer I was refering to " if I want to call without referring vtable, I used to use o.foo() rather than o->foo()" which appears to be based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: OK, I actually knows that the references and pointer are similar, they are all polymorphic. So I am not going to take about references. However, IMO, if I do `T t; t.foo()`, then `t` it not a reference, so it is not polymorphic, it has exactly the type `T`.

Comment: @calvin thats what I wrote in the answer, no?

Comment: Ok, what I am talking is like `Derived d; Base b = d; b.foo();`, then the b is copy-constructed from d, though it maybe "truncated". The b is exactly of type Base then. I know this code is kind of strange, however, I think it does not contradict to what you said in your answer?

Comment: @calvin no contradiction i see. Though I think you get too hung up by the middle paragraph. In your question you make a distinction between `a.foo()` and `a->foo()`. I thought the answer should clarify that `.` vs `->` is not what decides whether virtual dispatch is applied or not. I think you agree. Ok, once we agree on that, its not actually relevant for your actual quesiton of whether the standard mandates the use of a  vtable or not. It doesnt.